# Suppose $T : \mathbb R ^ n \to \mathbb R ^ n$ is a linear map which satisfies $T ^ k = O$ for some positive integer $k$. Show that $T ^ n = O$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove this problem:
Suppose $T : \mathbb R ^ n \to \mathbb R ^ n$
is a linear map which satisfies $T ^ k = O$ for some positive integer $k$.
Show that $T ^ n = O$ and $O$ is the $0$ map with dimensions $n \times n$.

This is what I have so far:

Let $w + k = n$ and let $w > 0$

Then, $T ^ n = (T ^ k)(T ^ w) = O$

I just can't figure how to prove this problem in the case that $w < 0$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m$ the smallest number so that $T^m=0$. It's enough to show that $m\le n$. 
From the definition of $m$, there exists a vector $v$ so that $T^{m-1}v\ne 0$. We will show that the vectors $v$, $Tv$, $\ldots$, $T^{m-1}v$ are linearly independent. Assume the contrary. There exist $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_{m-1}$ not all zero, so that
$$a_0 v+ a_1 Tv +\cdots + a_{m-1} T^{m-1} v = 0$$
Let $k$ the smallest index such that $a_k\ne 0$. We have therefore
$$a_k T^{k} v = -(a_{k+1}T^{k+1}v + \cdots + a_{m-1}T^{m-1}v)$$
Apply to both sides of the equality above the operator $T^{m-1-k}$. On the left hand side we get $a_k T^{m-1}v \ne 0$, while on the right hand side we get $0$, contradiction. Therefore, the $m$ vectors are linearly independent, and so $m\le n$.

Alternative proof: from the Hamilton-Cayley theorem, we conclude that for some $k \le n$, $T^k$ is a linear combination of higher powers of $T$, and a similar argument as above shows that $T^k = 0$, and so $T^n=0$.

Comment: why does it matter if v, Tv, ... is linearly independent?

Comment: and why is T ^ m - 1 - k applied to the right side equal 0?

Comment: @Kevin Weng: There are $m$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $m\le n$. Also, if you apply to RHS, each term contains $T$ to a power at least $m$, so it's $0$.

Comment: Hi @orangeskid, I'm still confused as to what happened to the terms a0, a1,etc. Why can you replace them with ak, ak+1??

Comment: @Kevin Weng: $k$ is the smallest index so that $a_k$ is $\ne 0$. So the $a_i$ with $i<k$ are all $0$. Of course, $k$ can be $0$, in that case there are no $a$'s of lower index.

Answer (score 2):

As $T^k=0$ then the minimal polynomial of $T$ is a factor of $x^k$,
so is $x^r$ for some $r$. But the minimal polynomial of a linear map on $\Bbb R^n$ has degree at most $n$, so $r\le n$. Therefore $T^r=0$,
and so $T^n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

First note that $T$ cannot have a nonzero eigenvalue, else there would be some eigenvector $v$ with $Tv=\lambda v$ and hence $T^kv=\lambda^kv\neq 0$.  Thus all eigenvalues of $T$ are zero.

Now we find $T$'s [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) $T=QUQ^{-1}$, where $U$ is upper triangular with $0$ (the eigenvalues of $T$) on the diagonal.  It is possible to do this with $Q,U$ real, since all eigenvalues of $T$ are real. For details of the real Schur decomposition, see [here](http://kurser.lobner.dk/LinAlg/Tilf%C2%B0jelser%20til%20Leons%20bog/RealSchur.pdf).

Now, $T^n=(QUQ^{-1})^n=QU^nQ^{-1}=Q0Q^{-1}=0$.  The key part is that $U^n=0$; each additional power of $U$ has one more superdiagonal all zero.